# Iterating over a C# range

Tags: c#

Using GetEnumerator extensions added in C# 9 I was able to do the following:

```
    public static class Extensions
    {   
        public static IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator(this Range range)
        {
            var start = range.Start.Value;
            var end = range.End.Value;            

            var current = start;
            while (current <= end)
            {
                yield return current++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Which enables me to do this neat thing:

```
foreach (var i in 1..5)
{
     Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

What I want to know is what are potential problems or side effects. Apart from a little performance loss, what downsides can you see if I would write like this in the future instead of using a for loop?

Comment: Since it doesnt support 1..5.Select(i => ) I say Enumerable.Range still wins

Comment: Which part of **your code** should be reviewed? Or are you looking for details about a new C# 9 feature?